# How to read serial port data in Bash/Python and convert it to human readable format?

Tags: python, linux, bash, serial-port

I am trying to convert the data received from an serial port into a human readable format.

If I run the following command

`stdbuf -o0 cat /dev/ttyS0 >/tmp/ttyS0.log`

I get

`x▒▒x▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xx▒▒x▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xx▒▒x▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xx▒▒x▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xx▒▒`

If I run

`xxd < /dev/ttyS0`

I get

```
0000010: 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078 f8f8 7880  ........x..x..x.
0000020: 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078  ............x..x
0000030: f8f8 7880 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080  ..x.............
0000040: 7800 0078 f8f8 7880 0080 0080 0080 0080  x..x..x.........
0000050: 0080 0080 7800 0078 f8f8 7880 0080 0080  ....x..x..x.....
0000060: 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078 f8f8 7880  ........x..x..x.
0000070: 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078  ............x..x
0000080: f8f8 7880 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080  ..x.............
0000090: 7800 0078 f8f8 7880 0080 0080 0080 0080  x..x..x.........
00000a0: 0080 0080 7800 0078 f8f8 7880 0080 0080  ....x..x..x.....
00000b0: 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078 f8f8 7880  ........x..x..x.
00000c0: 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 0080 7800 0078  ............x..x
```

I tried different baud rates and I only get a response with 9600.

The data comes from an industrial weight scale, I don't have any documentation for it.

The scope is to read the data and store it in file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

LE: I need to store the data in a human readable form. The scale I think will return the data in the form of measured quantity and measuring unit (ex - 5 kg).

The code that I tried

```
import serial
import time
import csv

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0')
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-8].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
        with open("/tmp/test_data.csv","a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            writer.writerow([time.time(),decoded_bytes])
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

the code doesn't return/store anything.

The only "results" that I had are with the bash commands above, but don't know how to translate the data returned into human readable form.

Comment: So you manage to read the data. You want to store it as it is ? or convert it somehow ? Please explain a bit more, maybe test with different known weigth objects, and show a working piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added more info at the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: Is the output changing when you weight 10kg, and 1Kg object ? 0,5 kg object ? or not ?

Comment: Yes, the output returned using the xxd command is different when the weight is changed. The output is returned in similar format, I tried to convert it using websites like rapidtables.com but I don't get any readable info.

Comment: I found this, maybee you can try this to read the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66569578/is-it-possible-to-use-pyqt5-qtserialport-without-guis-or-classes

Comment: Maybee you can show the weight used, and the data for several cases, so we can try finding a pattern ?

Comment: I managed to find some info documentation that suggested to use a baud rate of 2400 and I managed to get the data in ascii text. @Malo - Thanks for your help.