# Is it possible to use PyQt5 QtSerialPort without GUI's or classes?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-signals, qtserialport

The point would be to have the functionality of reading only when there is something to be read, instead of using pyserial which doesn't have a special method for that. I guess this may go into a bigger question of whether signals and slots could be used without a GUI classes (that inherit from other objects). I could get the serial port to write, but not read, with

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtSerialPort
serial_port = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort('COM3')
serial_port.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
serial_port.write(bytes([255]))

def handle_ready_read():
    while serial_port.canReadLine():
        print(serial_port.readAll())
        print('here')
        serial_port.close()

serial_port.readyRead.connect(handle_ready_read)
```

Nothing prints out, even though something is read when using pyserial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need GUI to use Qt. There is a dedicated [GUI module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html) in Qt and what does not depend on it, doesn't need a GUI.

However, to use slots and signals you need to run Qt's event loop. The regular way would be to use a [`QCoreApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html).

```py
app = QCoreApplication([])

# setup your serial port here

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok, I need to add ```app.quit()``` at the end of the loop for this to end--adding that at the very bottom doesn't seem to end the app.

Comment: The event loop concept is driven by the idea of indefinitely waiting for events, so `app.exec_()` is supposed to return only when all work is done. This implies that if you need your application to quit, you need to implement the logic that will signal it before calling `exec_()`.